# Android: Apply the same DropDownViewResource for spinner, but different results in action bar and activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-styles

I have an issue to put spinner in action bar.

I apply the same DropDownViewResource for the spinners in action bar and in activity content, but the results are different.

(Action Bar spinner)
[image]

(Activity spinner)
[image]

The following is the code:

(Activity)

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // apply custom layout for action bar
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.layout_actionbar_stylist_collections);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stylist_collections);

        mCollectionsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.collections_spinner);
        setSpinner(mCollectionsSpinner);

        mContentSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.content_spinner);
        setSpinner(mContentSpinner);
    }
    private void setSpinner(Spinner spinner) {
        String[] strList = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout_spinner_item, strList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.layout_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

(Action Bar layout: layout_actionbar_stylist_collections)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/collections_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

(Activity layout: activity_stylist_collections.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/content_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

(Spinner DropDownViewResource: layout_spinner_dropdown_item.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#0AA0A0" />
```

But it's weird that the outputs are different.
The background colors are different.

Anyone knows why?
Is it possible due to the action bar style?
And how can I make the spinner in action bar to be the same as the one in activity content?

Thanks in advance.
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution.
And yes, it results from the action bar style.

The original action bar style is as follows:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
</style>
```

After changing the "AppTheme" parent from "AppBaseTheme" to "@style/Theme.Holo.Light", problem solved.

Thanks all.
Eric